# ¿Cómo contar registros duplicados y, al mismo tiempo, poder imprimir otros datos en PHP y MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo el siguiente registro en mi tabla `logtrama`:

```
id_logtrama    fechaHora    idCliente    idEquipo
    1          2021-04-18       20          8
    2          2021-04-18       20          8
    3          2021-04-18       20          8
    4          2021-04-18       20          1
    5          2021-04-18       4           4
```

Y, en mi tabla `equipo` lo siguiente:

```
idEquipo    idCliente     tipo
    1          20        Alarm1
    2          1         Alarm2
    3          2         Alarm3
    8          20        Alarm4
```

Ahora, a través de mi consulta, imprimo resultados que coinciden con las condiciones dadas y, sin repetidos:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT l.id_logtrama,
                                    l.fechaHora,
                                    l.idCliente,
                                    l.idEquipo,
                                    l.statusGlobal
                                FROM logtrama l
                                JOIN equipo e
                                    ON l.idEquipo=e.idEquipo
                                    AND l.idCliente=e.idCliente
                                JOIN
                                    (SELECT MAX(t.id_logtrama) id_logtrama,
                                        COUNT(*) totals
                                    FROM logtrama t
                                    JOIN equipo e
                                        ON e.idEquipo = t.idEquipo
                                        AND e.idCliente = t.idCliente
                                    GROUP BY t.idcliente, t.idequipo) c
                                    ON c.id_logtrama = l.id_logtrama
                                WHERE DATE(fechaHora)=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $date_day);
```

En otras palabras, ya no me imprimirá los duplicados:

```
    1          2021-04-18       20          8
    2          2021-04-18       20          8
    3          2021-04-18       20          8
    4          2021-04-18       20          1
```

obtendré el siguiente resultado:

```
    3          2021-04-18       20          8
    4          2021-04-18       20          1
```

Ya en PHP sería:

```
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo 'ID logtrama: '.$id_logtrama.' Fecha: '.$fechaHora.' ID cliente: '.$pag_idCliente.' ID equipo: '.$pag_idEquipo.'';
    }
```

Salida:

```
ID logtrama: 3 Fecha: 2021-04-18 ID cliente: 20 ID equipo: 8
ID logtrama: 4 Fecha: 2021-04-18 ID cliente: 20 ID equipo: 1
```

Hasta ahora todo bien, pero necesito también poder contar los registros repetidos para imprimirlos, por ejemplo:

```
    1          2021-04-18       20          8
    2          2021-04-18       20          8
    3          2021-04-18       20          8
    4          2021-04-18       20          1
```

Se puede ver `1, 2, 3` tienen datos repetidos, entonces como puedo tener la siguiente salida de datos:

```
ID logtrama: 3 Fecha: 2021-04-18 ID cliente: 20 ID equipo: 8 Total de registro repetidos: (3)
ID logtrama: 4 Fecha: 2021-04-18 ID cliente: 20 ID equipo: 1 Total de registro repetidos: (1)
```

En la misma consulta que condiciones debo emplear para poder imprimir lo que deseo lograr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No entiendo por qué haces otro JOIN de las mismas dos tablas en una sub-consulta. Algo así debería funcionar:

```
                         SELECT 
                                MAX(l.id_logtrama) AS id_logtrama,
                                MAX(l.fechaHora) AS fechaHora,
                                l.idCliente,
                                l.idEquipo,
                                MAX(l.statusGlobal) AS statusGlobal,
                                COUNT(*) AS total
                            FROM logtrama l
                            JOIN equipo e
                                ON l.idEquipo=e.idEquipo
                                AND l.idCliente=e.idCliente 
                           WHERE DATE(l.fechaHora)=?
                           GROUP BY l.idcliente, e.idequipo
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123153/discussion-on-answer-by-a-cedano-como-contar-registros-duplicados-y-al-mismo).

Answer (score 0):

Si agrupas por cliente, equipo y fecha, el máximo id de trama es el que buscas, y el conteo sale naturalmente:

```
SELECT max(l.id_logtrama) 
     , max(l.fechaHora)
     , l.idCliente
     , l.idEquipo
     , count(1) duplicado
  FROM logtrama l
    JOIN equipo e
      ON    e.idEquipo  = l.idEquipo
        AND e.idCliente = l.idCliente
  WHERE date(l.fechaHora) = '2021-04-18'
  GROUP BY l.idCliente, l.idEquipo, date(l.fechaHora) 
  ORDER BY 1
```

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uYEPom9Cuf4Fh9fkGvPXX8/2)

Comment: Hola y, con que imprimo el número de veces repetido ya que el `COUNT` no veo que tengo un `AS`, para agregarlo al `$stmt->bind_result(...`

Comment: @Valentina Pon el alias que gustes a la columna, y usa ese mismo en PHP.

Comment: no funciona, me imprime todos los repetidos y, no me contabiliza el número de repetidos https://jsfiddle.net/pgxjev3m/

Comment: @Val Con las adecuaciones que hiciste se ve bien.

Comment: agregue captura a mi pregunta de lo que deseo por si no esta clara mi pregunta.

Comment: @Valentina: El tipo de dato era importante, respuesta actualizada.

Comment: solo los datos, tal cual deseo imprimir la información en mi última imagen adjunta.

Comment: Si entiendes por *duplicado* cuántos tienen la fecha del criterio, entonces sólo tienes que quitarle el `HAVING` a la consulta y obtendrás lo que esperas. Generalmente por *duplicado* se entiende aquellos registros que están más de una vez en una consulta concreta. Parece que aquí por duplicado te refieres a total por cada grupo.

Comment: @Sal El código que yo tengo me imprime el siguiente resultado https://i.stack.imgur.com/JviJN.png solo falta agregar el dato de duplicados

Comment: @Valentina El detalle es que iniciaste la pregunta indicando un tipo DATE y mostrando únicamente la fecha; cuando en realidad el tipo es DATETIME y al parecer también quieres que se muestre la hora. Creo que lo mejor para todos, es que revises y corrijas la pregunta completa.